# Rewriting .htaccess to remove index.php with alias url on codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have an issue with .htaccess codeigniter on our website (www.jp.com => first project)
I just recently built a new project and i set and accessed by an aliased link. (www.jp.com/pt => second project).

A path looks like this : 
first project : /var/www/jp
second project : /var/www/pt

The problem, if i access this url : "www.jp.com/pt" it's works,
but.. if i access others controller, e.g: "www.jp.com/pt/news" where i'm not set a controller as a default controller, the page shown 404 not found.

And then,i try using index.php like this, "www.jp.com/pt/index.php/news" It's works..

Can anyone help me to fixing this ? i'll can access my alias link without index.php

I using CI 2 & PHP 5.3

**Here is my code (mixed from many references :D )**

Current .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|public)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.jp.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

My Config.php :

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = "$root";
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

The .htaccess RewriteBase in the codeigniter second project directory should say /pt/

```
RewriteBase /pt
```

Otherwise the rewrite to index.php ends up going to  first project router.